# "Custom" selection mode in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have set up a DataGridView which shows hourly values in a grid (1 column for each day, 24 rows). For my users' convenience, I would like them to be able to easily select a time interval and include all the values in between (see pictures). Preferably via a Shift+Click+DrawMouse operation, or a Click followed by a Shift+Click.

This doesn't seem to be a standard selection mode in DataGridView. Does anyone have a suggestion for solving this?

[image: Right way] 
[image: Wrong way]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom selection with C# DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145623/custom-selection-with-c-sharp-datagridview)

Comment: Yep, that looks like it will help.  Sorry, don't know why I didn't find that earlier.  Should I close this question?

Comment: Decision belongs to you ;)